# Put elements of a table in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I have a table with elements and i want to put that elements in one array INDEPENDENTLY of how many rows or cells that table want. 
i already have an empty table created and a code to add elements from a input, and now and want to put that information in a list so that afterwards if you want to delete an element in the list, also delete in the table.

HTML

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" name="nome" id="nomedisciplina">    
<button onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar disciplina</button><br>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function adicionar() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("nomedisciplina").value;
}
```

This already make me the table , now i don't know who to make the rest

Comment: Each element in the array should represent a row? A cell?

Comment: The table will only have one cell.

Comment: Are you using a table for one cell? why?

Comment: I'm using this to do a web page , that will be about study  , and i want to put a list of the thing that he have to study , that's why i need only 1 cell , you think i have a better option to do this ?

Comment: If it's only one cell, use <li> instead.